# Custom Control switching between two styles

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm making a custom control which has two very different styling needs. One for a basic look, and another for a more advanced look.

My control contains a dependency property for the following enum:

```
public enum ControlTypes
{
    Basic,
    Advanced
}
```

I created two styles in the generic.xaml (with very different templates), and gave each a key.

Inside the change handler for the enum property I'm trying to find the styles and set the correct one.

```
private static void OnControlTypePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var myCustomControl = (MyCustomControl)d;

    var basicControlStyle = Application.Current.TryFindResource("BasicControlStyle") as Style;
    var advancedControlStyle = Application.Current.TryFindResource("AdvancedControlStyle") as Style;

    if (myCustomControl.ControlType == ControlTypes.Basic)
        myCustomControl.Style = basicControlStyle;
    else if (myCustomControl.ControlType == ControlTypes.Advanced)
        myCustomControl.Style = advancedControlStyle;            
}
```

The two styles are always null. I'm not sure how to get the styles from inside the generic.xaml. Or is there a better way to swap my styles?

Comment: How about simply binding the Visible property of each container to the current value of the enum?

Comment: The control has several required parts which are the same for both templates (despite the templates being radically different). I'm currently finding the template parts inside the ApplyTemplate override. What your suggesting would work if I gave each part a unique name, and reacquired them (using each parts second name) when the control type changed. This quirky design would be nice to avoid.

Comment: In that case, you could just bind the Visibility property to the "IsAdvancedStyle" property in your control (rather than referencing everything by name from your control) - but that's not the optimal solution. Does the result from `Application.Current.TryFindResource` return null? Does it return a non-`Style` instance? Don't forget that Resource names are case-sensitive. Has `generic.xaml` been correctly added to the main application resource collection?

Comment: The control and generic.xaml are stored in a custom control library. If I override the metadata for the default style key I can define a keyless style in generic.xaml and it does apply. I double checked the case of my style keys and it is correct. As for the Application.Current.TryFindResource method, it does return null. I'm doubtful "Application.Current" is the correct place to look for my styles (since it's returning null, I'd say it's definitely not). I tried this.TryFindResource but also got null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the code in OnControlTypePropertyChanged and put something like this in your XAML. Note that I have bound to a property called IsAdvanced because it was simpler for testing but you can bind to an enum by changing the "True" for {x:Static namespace:nameofyourenum.Value}

```
<Style TargetType="local:SomeControl">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SomeControl">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="DefaultTemplate"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsAdvanced" Value="True">
            <Trigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SomeControl">
                            <TextBlock Text="Advanced Template"></TextBlock>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger.Setters>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Note that this still give the programmer who uses your control the ability to completely override the control template and do what they want. Your original approach didn't allow this.